# Creating href in ruby using html slim

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

I am trying to create a href to link user(provider) name with user(provider) account view.

I am far from expert in this - tried to copy a part of script from other place in the code where it refers to user(provider) account.

The place where I am trying to add link is:

`= render partial: 'services/partials/messages/original_message', locals: { header: t('html.text.consultation_with.for_provider', name: @provider_user.name, type: t("element_names.#{@service.service_type}")),...`

and the the part of script which was used to refer to user(provider) account looks like this:

`[href="#{provider_path(provider)}" id="provider-#{provider.id}"]`

So I tried combining those two:

`= render partial: 'services/partials/messages/original_message', locals: { header: t('html.text.consultation_with.for_provider', name: [href="#{provider_path(provider)}" id="provider-#{provider.id}"], type: t("element_names.#{@service.service_type}")),...`

And was not surprised that it did not worked..

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix up slim element syntax (the one with square brackets, used by slim itself to create attributes of an element) with ruby code (the arguments to `render`, it's just a plain ruby method call!)

Maybe this would work for you, or some adaptation:

```
= render partial: 'services/partials/messages/original_message', 
         locals: { 
           header: t('html.text.consultation_with.for_provider', 
           name: @provider_user.name,
           provider_link_href: provider_path(provider),
           provider_link_id: "provider-#{provider.id}",
           type: t("element_names.#{@service.service_type}")),
           ...
         }
```

And then in the partial, use them like

```
a[href=provider_link_href id=provider_link_id]
  Text of the link
```

Comment: Thanks, but where exactly should `a[href=provider_link_href id=provider_link_id]
  Text of the link` be used/specified?  I tried to edit my _customer_view.html.slim file to add code as you described. But that alone doesn't work. Also in my case the Text of the link is `@provider_user.name`, which should be user(provider) name.